# How to go from grid to linear layout like Instagram?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to android dev. I am creating a gallery app where I am using grid layout to display images, like this image: 
[image: app screenshot]

It's working fine. But what I also want is when I click on a image, I want to open a fragment of linear recyclerView with the clicked image to be visible on screen, like this:
[image: image1]

[image: image2]

Now I don't know how to achieve this. I am a newbie . Please help(please ignore my poor English).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First make a interface:

```
public interface ItemClicklistner {
public void onclick(View view , int position , String titlename,String link);
```

}

Second Use this clicklistner and put the clicklistner on whole parent layout of your recyclerview layout.

```
public class TilesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TilesAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private LayoutInflater inflate;
private Context context;
private List<String> sections = new ArrayList<>();
private ItemClicklistner clicklistner;
 int[] imagelink ;

public TilesAdapter(Context context, List<String> sections, int[] image) {

    this.context =context;
    this.imagelink = image;
    inflate = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.sections = sections;
}

@Override
public TilesAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder( ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

 SectionchildBinding mBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflate,R.layout.sectionchild,parent,false);
    return new TilesAdapter.ViewHolder(mBinding);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(TilesAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.mbinding.titleImg.setImageResource(imagelink[position]);
    holder.mbinding.sectionName.setText(sections.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return sections.size();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {

    return position;
}

public void setClicklistner(ItemClicklistner clicklistner){
    this.clicklistner =clicklistner;
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    private SectionchildBinding mbinding;
    public ViewHolder(SectionchildBinding mBinding)
    {
        super(mBinding.getRoot());
                this.mbinding = mBinding;
                mBinding.childsectionlayout.setOnClickListener(this);(here is the we set the click on layout )

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(clicklistner !=null) clicklistner.onclick(v,getAdapterPosition(),"","");
    }
}
```

}

Third Implement Clicklistner on your activity where you call this recyclerview

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ItemClicklistner

public void onclick(View view, int position ,String decreption_name ,String link) {`this method give you the position and link of the image that you clicked}`
```

In this method you can call next fragment and send the image on your fragment.

If you want to add Grid layout

```
 layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    GridLayoutManager manager = new GridLayoutManager(this,2);(number of rows)
    mBinding.sectionlist.setLayoutManager(manager);(here you give  recyclerview refrence )
    Adapter = new TilesAdapter(MainActivity.this, sections,image);
    mBinding.sectionlist.setAdapter(Adapter);
    Adapter.setClicklistner(MainActivity.this);
```

Comment: AshishVE, will I be able to create a vertical linear recyclerview with this?

Comment: No this will help you to open fragment on particular click on image

Comment: No this is not what i want. I already can open a fragment on clicking an image and show it there. What I want is to go from grid layout to linear layout just like instagram.

Comment: bro on click on a image you have to open another grid layout on your fragment. please clarify more after click on image